# How to skip (X509) certificate validation in gocloak?

Tags: go, keycloak

I am trying to validate my token from keycloak using [gocloak](https://github.com/Nerzal/gocloak) and tyring the below code for that..

```
token:=""
client:= gocloak.NewClient("https://example.com")
_, err := client.RetrospectToken(token,"client-id" ,"client-secret", "realm")
log.Print(err.Error())
```

the I am getting below error,

`Post https://example.com/auth/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

is there any way to skip the certificate validation in gocloak.

Comment: your keycloack has self-signed certificates ?

Comment: no it's signed from global sign but I guess gocloak doen't understand the global signs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you are looking for the skipping validation of the certificates in TLS try this using `RestyClient`

```golang
token:=""
client := gocloak.NewClient(serverURL)
restyClient := client.RestyClient()
restyClient.SetDebug(true)
restyClient.SetTLSClientConfig(&tls.Config{ InsecureSkipVerify: true })
_, err := client.RetrospectToken(token,"client-id" ,"client-secret", "realm")
log.Print(err.Error())
```

Comment: let me try it once

Comment: yeah it's working like magic, and I know it's not good for production but it solved my problem :-)
thnx for the help